# Why does subtraction behave in the following way?

Tags: python

Following is the output of what I did in the python terminal.

```
math.modf(45.332)

(0.33200000000000074, 45.0)
```

So I felt that it was weird .... tried to mimic this modf function and got the same result..

```
k=lambda x : x-float(math.floor(x))

k(5.5)

0.5

k(45.332)

0.33200000000000074
```

Note : This is happening only  when the floating point has more than 1 digit

Answer (score 1):

When you call `modf(45.332)` in your code the input will actually be converted to a floating point number with value 45.332000732421874.

In other words your problem happens before you are using the mimic function `k(45.332)`, because that input argument will also be converted to float.

Comment: How does this help OP? Why would `45.332` in the script get converted to `45.332000732421874` in the first place (and note that that's the wrong value)? Isn't that confusing? There's a better answer to this, and it's already well covered in the proposed duplicate.

Comment: @Chris In addition to what is mentioned in the duplicate, OP seems to think that the problem lies with modf(), since he tried to implement a different function to replace it. So I'm just pointing out that the problem occurs before, and that it is due to "converted to a floating point number".

Comment: Fair point. But glossing over why OP is dealing with `45.33200000000000074` in the first place is very confusing. This answer doesn't stand by itself.

Comment: Thank you ! wow computers are so nuanced ....